# Unsupported major.minor 52.0 exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

Given such an exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

And I know this is because that the JDK and JRE are not compatible. However, when I type in:

```
which java
```

The output is:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/java
```

And when typing in:

```
which javac
```

The output is:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_24/bin/javac
```

It is the compatible in version. So what's the problem?

Comment: And how do you start the program that throws the exception ?

Comment: When running an 'ant' script, it contains some tasks about java. I think the path of javac is wrong. Do you know how to set up the path of javac?

Comment: Ant is using `JAVA_HOME` environment var.

Comment: can you paste the content of java/javac task in ant file or search for java and paste all that matches.

Comment: Version 52 = Java 8. You won't be able to run Java 8 software with Java 6

Comment: @PeterMmm you could override your java compiler path with executable attribute in javac tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is typically caused by this sequence:

- Code is compiled with new JDK, and "target" set to current version of Java.
- Attempt to run the code with an older JDK or JRE.

In this case, minor version 52 means that something has been compiled with a Java 8 JDK, and with Java 8 as the target platform, and that you are attempting to run it on an older JRE / JDK.

You could also have gotten a JAR file from somewhere else that was compiled for Java 8.

To solve your problem, you need to figure out:

- which class file or files have the version number problem (the exception message should tell you the first one ...),
- where the class file came from (from a JAR file? from the file system?), and then
- how come it was compiled with Java 8 though you *thought* you were compiling with Java 6.

It is an indisputable fact that the class that won't load *was* compiled using Java 8 (or later) compiler.  You need to figure out why, and then either recompile it with the older JDK, *or* run it with Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

it says version 52.0 so you should install java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Check if tools.jar used during compilation complies with the JRE set. If you are on eclipse, verify the versions as:

Goto Window->Preferences

- Check Ant Runtime by selecting Runtime under Ant in the left pane. Check the Global Entries under classpath tab. You can see the version in folder path.
- On the left pane check installed JREs under Java. Check the version.